# How test CORS in Spring Boot? When I try in MockMvcBuilders, it always returns 200 despite Origin being wrong

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit, mockito, mockmvc

The below tests (I included two classes to see if either one would work) both have no issues calling the controller. I want it to reject with a CORS issue as I have not added any CORS config. (I then want to test with a CORS config and have that pass).

How can I force a CORS failure?

First Attempt:

```
import com.testing.Application;
import com.testing.config.ControllerConfig;
import com.testing.controller.MyController;
import com.testing.dto.TestDateResponse;
import com.testing.exception.GlobalExceptionHandler;
import com.testing.service.TestService;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.ResultActions;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
import org.springframework.web.context.ConfigurableWebApplicationContext;

import java.time.LocalDate;

import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.equalTo;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.notNullValue;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.post;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.content;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class TestCORS
{
    @Autowired
    private ConfigurableWebApplicationContext context;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @InjectMocks
    private MyController myController;

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Before
    public void setup()
    {
        //Initialize our injected mocks
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        //Create a controller
        myController = new MyController( new TestService(), restTemplate );

        //Create an environment for it
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
            .webAppContextSetup(context)
            .dispatchOptions(true)
            .build();

        //Create our marshaller
        objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    }

    /**
     * Tests that we fail when trying to access cross origin
     * @throws Exception if json unmarshaller cannot parse the response
     */
    @Test
    public void testValidRequest() throws Exception
    {
        String request = "{\"asOfDate\":\"20170210\"}";

        //Call to test a date
        ResultActions actions = mockMvc.perform(
            post("/v1/testdate")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(request)

                //CORS HEADERS
                .header("Access-Control-Request-Method", "DELETE")
                .header("Origin", "https://evil.com")
        );

        actions.andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8));

        TestDateResponse response = objectMapper.readValue(actions.andReturn().getResponse().getContentAsString(), TestDateResponse.class);
        assertThat(response, notNullValue());
        // verify date has returned back correctly
        assertThat(response.getRetDate(), equalTo(LocalDate.of(2017, 02, 10)));
    }
}
```

Second Attempt:

```
import com.testing.config.ControllerConfig;
import com.testing.controller.MyController;
import com.testing.dto.TestDateResponse;
import com.testing.exception.GlobalExceptionHandler;
import com.testing.service.TestService;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.ResultActions;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import java.time.LocalDate;

import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.equalTo;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.notNullValue;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.post;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.content;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {ControllerConfig.class})
public class TestCORS
{
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;
    private MyController myController;

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Before
    public void setup()
    {
        //Initialize our injected mocks
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        //Create a controller
        myController = new MyController( new TestService(), restTemplate );

        //Create an environment for it
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(myController)
            .setControllerAdvice(new GlobalExceptionHandler())
            .build();

        //Create our marshaller
        objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    }

    /**
     * Tests that we fail when trying to access cross origin
     * @throws Exception if json unmarshaller cannot parse the response
     */
    @Test
    public void testValidRequest() throws Exception
    {
        String request = "{\"asOfDate\":\"20170210\"}";

        //Call to test a date
        ResultActions actions = mockMvc.perform(
            post("/v1/testdate")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(request)

                //CORS HEADERS
                .header("Access-Control-Request-Method", "GET")
                .header("Origin", "http://www.someurl.com")
        );
        actions.andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8));

        TestDateResponse response = objectMapper.readValue(actions.andReturn().getResponse().getContentAsString(), TestDateResponse.class);
        assertThat(response, notNullValue());
        // verify date has returned back correctly
        assertThat(response.getRetDate(), equalTo(LocalDate.of(2017, 02, 10)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

CORS does not work like that.

To check CORS a preflight call to the URL has to be made.
That is not a POST but an OPTIONS request against the very same URL with the CORS headers.

With that call you will receive the CORS response if the real call (against DELETE) is allowed or not.

Something like that should work:

```
    ResultActions actions = mockMvc.perform(
        options("/v1/testdate")    
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            //CORS HEADERS
            .header("Access-Control-Request-Method", "DELETE")
            .header("Origin", "https://evil.com")
    );
```

And then simply assert for the expected response headers.

Comment: I get this error: `javax.servlet.ServletException: No adapter for handler [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMapping$PreFlightHandler@82c57b3]: The DispatcherServlet configuration needs to include a HandlerAdapter that supports this handler`

Comment: Do you o have the cross origin configured on your RequestController or your RequestMapping?  e.g. with: @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://not-evil.com")

Comment: No, I don't. Do I need that? Will that fix this error?
Is there a way to make a custom adapter bean to get rid of this error?

Comment: That is beyond of my knowledge.